# self teach algorithms

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, book-recommendation

What are some good resources to self teach the subject of Algorithms for someone with background in mathematics?

That is, does there exists a more theoretical and abstract approach versus practical approach? I am a graduating math B.S. looking to self teach practical and marketable skills, but who prefers the kind of learning found in pure math.

Comment: my advice : prefer the practical approach, learn the C language, then C++

Comment: Try the books by Robert Sedgewick.

Comment: Try also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a very mathematical approach, two books I used together to learn about computational complexity and algorithms were [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) (Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik) and [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) (Knuth).

Neither of these books rely on any real-world programming languages, but if you can read and understand even a significant part of them, you will be in good shape. Depending on your background, that may be a difficult task, but it is worth it in my opinion.

**Edit:** Emulators exist for Knuth's MIX and MMIX, but the languages in *The Art of Computer Programming* are not "real-world" in any practical sense.